# Where does the practice of saying "the same" instead of "it/that/etc." come from in Indian English?

Tags: pronouns, etymology, indian-english

One often uses "the same" instead of "it/that/etc." in Indian English. [Example](https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/secret-whatsapp-group-with-over-100-ceos-as-member-comes-to-light-after-sam-altman-crisis-report-4659988):

> Meanwhile, Microsoft's chief technology officer Kevin Scott was informed by OpenAI's chief technology officer Mira Murati about the same.

Where does the use of "the same" to replace "it/that/etc." come from?

Comment: This example doesn't seem particularly unusual to me as a native British English speaker. It's not specifically Indian, at least in this sentance.

Comment: My gut feel is this usage was more common in Victorian Britain, and it's not uncommon to find "fossilized" Victorian forms in Indian English. But as @timchessish says, this one isn't *that* unusual - but I'm quite prepared to believe it's more common in IE than in "mainstream" English today.

Comment: I can confirm the premise; I have a lot of Indian coworkers and often hear constructions like "If you approve my code I'll be able to merge the same."

Comment: We have [Why do speakers from India frequently use the phrase "the same"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217389/why-do-speakers-from-india-frequently-use-the-phrase-the-same) on EL&U, but I'm skeptical about the answer
there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a relevant chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20the%20same%20when&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

where as you can see, the usage under consideration peaked in the mid-1800s. Note that I specifically searched for *"of the same **when**"* to screen out at least some "false positives" like *Here's another of the same **kind*** (from a quick glance, I see most matches have a full stop or comma after ***same***).

Obviously not *all* of the instances contributing to that chart are the same context as OP's - but I think enough of them will be that we can draw a tentative conclusion from the chart.

Specifically, my conclusion is that the usage under consideration was more common in Victorian Britain. It's not uncommon to find "fossilized" Victorian forms in Indian English - and although this one isn't *very* unusual, it's quite likely that it's more common in Indian English than in "mainstream" English today..

Comment: And earlier still. Compare Psalm 113 v3 in the King James Bible - _From the rising of the sun unto the going down of the same the Lord's name is to be praised._ More modern versions use _to its setting_, or even _from east to west_.

Comment: Dang! If I'd thought of that, I'd have used ***the*** for my "false positive screening word" instead of ***when***. I just did that - it advances "peak usage" by a couple of decades, but tells essentially the same story.